# Question Regarding the Definition of a "Stable Permutation Representation"

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, definition, group-actions

I am looking at some of my old Representation Theory work in advance of a visiting research fellow project in the area I am seeking to undertake in the coming weeks.

The lecturer wrote that "a permutation representation is a representation of the form $\mathbb{C}[X]$ for a $G$-set $X$, and a *stable permutation representation* is a representation $V$ so that $V \oplus \mathbb{C}[Y]$ is a permutation for some $G$-set $Y$." They then left the following as an exercise, and I am stumped by it.

- Give an example of a stable permutation representation that is not a permutation representation.

My previous self wrote the hint: "construct a $G$-set from disjoint unions of copies of $G=C_2$ and the fixed-point set of $G$ acting on the $G$-set X" but I feel I have misunderstood the definition to the point that this is almost meaningless to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never heard the term "stable permutation representation" before, and the first hit if you Google it is this question, which is a sign that it's not in widespread use.

Comment: Call the two irreducible  representations of $C_2$ $1$ and $-1$, where $1$ is the trivial representation. Then $-1$ is not a permutation representation, but $-1 +1+1$ is and so is $-1 + (-1 + 1 + 1) =  (-1+1)+(-1+1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I was being over-complicated! $-1$ is not a permutation representation, but $1$ and $-1+1$ are.

Comment: You are absolutely right, Derek. Thank you very much for your help. Taking $G = X = C_{2} = \{Id, g \}$ with the $Id$ acting as $1$ and $g$ acting as $-1$ yields precisely the answer. Indeed we see this is not a permutation representation by considering the fact that we require  $\chi_{\mathbb{C}[X]}(g) = | X^{g} |$ (the number of points of $X$ fixed by $g$.